# How should I handle the errors when I try to write in DB

Tags: http, go, error-handling, server

Not sure how should I deal with errors when I try to write in DB in this particular case:

So I use this func to insert in DB

```
func SaveToDB(dateid string, content string) {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbLink)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    queryString := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO balances (dateid, content) VALUES('%v','%v');", dateid, content)

    rows, err := db.Query(queryString)
    if err != nil {
          log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
}
```

But I would like to don't stop the server when error is duplicate so I tried this version:

```
func SaveToDB(dateid string, content string) {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbLink)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    queryString := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO balances (dateid, content) VALUES('%v','%v');", dateid, content)

    rows, err1 := db.Query(queryString)
    if err1 != nil {
        thisErr, err2 := regexp.MatchString("Error 1062: Duplicate entry", err.Error())
        if err2 != nil {
            log.Fatal("ERROR: error occured while trying to perform regex on SaveToDB", err2)
        }
        if thisErr == true {
            log.Println("ERROR: Not able to save in DB due to ducplicate: ", err1)
        }else{log.Fatal("ERROR: error occured when trying to save to DB: ", err1)}
    }
    defer rows.Close()
}
```

But in this situation I receive panic. So how I can stop this function from executing before it reaches "defer rows.Close()"? I guess that is the reason for panic...

Comment: Return an error, as normal, and let the caller handle it as it sees fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `log.Fatal` and install deferred code once you have the correct data:

```
rows, err := db.Query(queryString)
if err != nil {
    log.Error(err)
    return
} 
defer rows.Close()
```

Comment: Replace the return with your error handling code, then. The point is, do not use `defer rows.Close()` if there was an error, because `rows` is nil.

Comment: I used your sugestion but instead of handling the error in this function I assigned it to a global error then checked in another part of the code. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if a global state is the best approach, why not just return the error so the caller can handle it?

Comment: As others said, return the error if you cannot handle it.